# CoreData: Move objects from one ArrayController to another

Tags: ios, macos, swift, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I have two `NSArrayControllers` that use Core Data entities and I want to move objects at certain indices (via `NSIndexSet`) from one AC to the other. Normally this would be easy but here it's not because Core Data is under it and if I try it, it seems to remove the objects from the source AC but not adding them to the target AC. I'm using this code:

```
extension NSIndexSet
{
    func toArray() -> [Int]
    {
        var indexes:[Int] = [];
        self.enumerateIndexesUsingBlock
            {
                (index:Int, _) in
                indexes.append(index);
        }
        return indexes;
    }
}

func moveIndicesToTargetAC(indexSet:NSIndexSet)
{
    let a = indexSet.toArray();
    for i in a
    {
        var obj:NSManagedObject = sourceArrayController?.arrangedObjects.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSManagedObject;
        targetArrayController?.addObject(obj);
        sourceArrayController?.removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex(i);
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to have Core Data regard the deletions and additions?

Comment: Do different array controllers use the same instance of NSManagedObjectContext ? If not you might have to fetch the object with same managedObjectID from the other managedObjectContext. By the way, doesn't array controller handle the managedObjectContext by itself ?

Comment: They use the same MOC. I suppose the array controller manages all the underlying core data relations. I think I know what the problem is now: The two array controllers manage different kinds of entities, even though they have the same fields. That probably can't work out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new NSArray from a NSArray? In objC it looks like this: [NSArray arrayWithArray: ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for hints anyone! I solved the issue by creating a new object of the target (NSManagedObject) entity and transfer all the data over to it. It was indeed an issue because the core data entities of the two ACs is different.